# How does the path function in Data.Graph work in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, graph, functional-programming

I have read the documentation that I can find on the path function (**for a directed graph**). There isn't much coming up in the search engine.

All I found basically boils down to [this link](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.6.3/docs/html/libraries/containers-0.6.0.1/Data-Graph.html).

All it really says is what the path function does (which I already knew), and and example of output. What I am trying to figure out, is how the path function works or how it could be implemented manually. So far I have gotten this far but am now stuck (or may be on the wrong path altogether, I can't be certain):

```
member _ [] = False
member n (x:xs)
    | x == n = True
    | otherwise = membre n xs
    
getX :: (a, b) -> a
getX (x,_) = x

getY :: (a, b) -> b
getY (_,y) = y

getAllY :: [(a , b)] -> [b]
getAllY [] = [] 
getAllY (x:xs) = (getY x):(getAllY xs)

fltrX [] _ = []
fltrX (x:xs) n 
    | (getX x) == n = x:(fltrX xs n)
    | otherwise = fltrX xs n
    
fltrY [] _ = []
fltrY (x:xs) n 
    | (getY x) == n = x:(fltrY xs n)
    | otherwise = fltrY xs n

path' :: [(a , a)] -> a -> a -> Bool
path' [] _ _ = False
path' (xs) n m 
    | (member m (getAllY (fltrX xs n))) = True
    | otherwise = *recursive statement giving me a headache*
```

but I am having trouble seeing how to get the recursion right. I think I have just been staring at it too long and can't see the whole problem clearly anymore. Logic should be something like:

- it takes the y values from the tuples with x = n
- it finds all tuples where x in the list of Y values above
- if no Y values = m, do path function on new list of tuples with n = (each of the X values) and m = m
- if m is found in the Y values, return true

Can anyone point me in the right **direction** (pun intended) preferably without typing out the code for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of [graph traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal)? Because that's what `path` does (in particular, depth-first search).

Comment: Did you take a look at [the actual implementation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.3/docs/html/libraries/containers-0.6.0.1/src/Data-Graph.html#path)?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I do understand the concept, it's the implementation I haven't gotten right yet

Comment: @Bergi Cool, I was looking for something like that but I guess I missed it

Comment: @Bulbasaur It's available if you click the "Source" link in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to commenters for providing resources that helped me write the following solution :

```
member _ [] = False
member n (x:xs)
    | x == n = True
    | otherwise = member n xs
    
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs)
    | member x xs == True = unique xs
    | otherwise = x:(unique xs)


findAllEndsForX :: [(Int , Int)] -> Int -> [Int]
findAllEndsForX [] _ = []
findAllEndsForX ((a,b):xs) y
  | xs == [] = a:[b]
  | a == y = a:(findAllEndsForX xs b)
  | otherwise = (findAllEndsForX xs b)

accessible :: [(Int , Int)] -> Int -> [Int]
accessible [] _ = []
accessible xs n = unique (findAllEndsForX xs n)

path' :: [(Int , Int)] -> Int -> Int -> Bool
path' [] _ _ = False
path' xs v w = member w (accessible xs v)
```

My ultimate goal was to mimic the functionality of the path feature, not necessarily the implementation. I wanted to do the work without using any predefined functions.

Comment: Inspiring code! And very clear to read, thanks for sharing. One question though: I have the impression that the first guard of `findAllEndsForX` is incomplete. I mean the following line : `| xs == [] = a:[b]` is not testing that `y` is either `a` or `b`, which could not hold true.